# java incompatible types compiler error

Tags: java

I am new to Java, this code is giving me errors while compiling:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sorts {


    public List<Integer> ascendent(List<Integer> list) {
          return Collections.sort(list);
        }
    public List<Integer> descendant(List<Integer> list) {
          return Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sorts sorts = new Sorts(); 

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5,5));

        System.out.println(sorts.ascendent(list).toString());    
    }

}
```

The errors are on the lines return from ascendent and descendent method:

incompatible types
required: java.util.List (java.lang.Integer)
  found:    void

But it seems to me that I am casting my ListArray object correctly, what is wrong ?

Comment: What line is the error on? (Also: "it seems to me that I am casting my ListArray object correctly" - there is not a single cast in your code).

Comment: line 7 and 10, on return statements!

Comment: right. And what type should those methods be returning? And what type do you actually have them returning? The error message actually tells you exactly what is wrong! ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Collections.sort` is `void`, you cannot use it in a `return` statement.

Also, `Collections.sort` modifies the original list, so you don't have to return a new list at all.

Remove the `return`:

```
public void ascendent(List<Integer> list) {
      Collections.sort(list);
}
public void descendant(List<Integer> list) {
      Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
}
```

Also, change your code accordingly. This:

```
System.out.println(sorts.ascendent(list).toString());
```

Must be changed to:

```
sorts.ascendent(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Change signature to "public void"

Answer (score 3):

See [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))

> public static ... **void** sort(List list)

It does not return the sorted list, it just sorts your list.

You need:

```
Collections.sort(list);
return list;
```